# difference in font for sans serif

Tags: fonts

I'm looking to use a sans serif font that looks like this

[image]

but when using a particular LaTeX template, the same sans serif font looks like the following:

[image]

which is not the font I'm looking for; it's too thin despite it already being in bold face. The culprit seems to be this line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

which, when deleted, causes the 2nd font to look like the first font. Why is this the case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot. Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: To follow up on @Mensch's comment: Does your employ the `fontspec` package? If so, is there a `\setsansfont` directive? If there is, what's the argument of that instruction?

Comment: If you [can find out what font that is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture), you can use it with `fontspec` or see if there is an 8-bit version on [the LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fonts used with OT1 and T1 encoding are different as the cm-super fonts used for T1 cover much more font sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily
Investigation

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
Investigation
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first font is a 10pt-font `cmssbx10.pfb` which has been scaled up and so is very bold, the second is a font specifically designed for this font size  `sfsx2488.pfb`.

You could force the use of scaled up fonts with T1-encoding too, but imho it is better to use the properly designed fonts.