# How to get a font weight bolder than \textbf{}?

Tags: beamer, bold, frame

I have been trying to reproduce a Beamer presentation template from a former teacher but I can't find out how they managed to change the font weight to be this bold.

[image: Comparison here]

How can I get the font on the right to be as bold as the one on the left ?

```
{\color{white} \huge \textbf{Cryptographic Tools}}
```

is what I used, the size looks correct but the weight is clearly not the same as the left one.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are perhaps  using T1 encoding https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619267/2388

Comment: Thank you ! That is indeed, the case and it looks way better now. However, since I am writing in french, is there any risk that something else breaks ? I was under the impression that it was necessary for accent and such (Although so far they seem to be fine).

Comment: @rlepretre You can load the Latin Modern font instead. It looks basically the same as the default, the T1 bold looks like the default one and it is still a T1 font.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{amsbsy} \pmb{...text...}`